# How to show contacts in popup?

Tags: android, popup, contacts

I knew their are many reference for contacts list but what I need was to get the contacts in popup menu.

When user click on button popup should show the contacts list he should be able to select the multiple friends name and contact number store them.

I had gone with the below code and get only by information I kept the popup and tried I need exactly as our mobile contacts list view.

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public TextView outputText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
fetchContacts();

}


public void fetchContacts() {

String phoneNumber = null;
String email = null;

Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

Uri EmailCONTENT_URI =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;

StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);  

// Loop for every contact in the phone
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID );
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( DISPLAY_NAME );
int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( HAS_PHONE_NUMBER ));
if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
output.append("\n First Name:" + name);

// Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);

while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber);
}

phoneCursor.close();

// Query and loop for every email of the contact
Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EmailCONTENT_URI,    null, EmailCONTACT_ID+ " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);

while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {

email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA));

output.append("\nEmail:" + email);


}

emailCursor.close();
}

output.append("\n";
}

outputText.setText(output);
}
}

}
```

If some have any idea about this please help me friends.

Comment: I dont see any popupmenu releted code above. Just a heads up popup menu requires a anchor view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create a button and on that button click

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.email_dialog);//

        ListView lv;
        lv= (ListView ) dialog.findViewById(R.id.list);//this is your list xml
```

Use a multiple choice listview adapter and populate the contacts in the list view using the above code

Comment: sir actually i'm new to android can you please give me some related sample and can you guide me for go ahead

Comment: check out this link http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/09/listview-with-multiple-choice.html                      and use your code to get the contacts and put that list in the adapter

Comment: ok sir i had gone with above code it i used to select the multiple friends contacts futher i need to save it for that should i go with contant values and store it in DB or some easy way is there ha.

Comment: @user3737339: dont call me sir and all bro, the best way is to actually save it in the db so that you can use it where ever in ur application

Comment: if you need just one or two contacts you can save it in shared preference

Comment: ok george let me try it out first and let me know for you if any issues again will u plz guide me i don't have many reputation to contact u directly can u plz send your EmailID so that it will be use full to me to clarify my issues.

Comment: @user3737339:ya sure you can contact me at georgethms10@gmail.com,happy to help

Comment: no i should go on with plenty of contacts for that contant value only be fine

Comment: the above link for reference give by you is there they use to set the details hardcore

Comment: sorry i didn't understand

Comment: what i mean to say was that when contacts list appear we should be able to select multiple contacts in list as we usually select the contacts to send message in group know like that then i'm getting the list and then i used contactloader to save the datas and get the details by view in as view normally see in our mobiles.

Comment: simple way was as we normally do in our mobiles by selecting our friends in group and send message know like that way bro..